# how do I set the values of an array in Objective-C using .notation?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, syntax

Sorry I'm new to Objective-C and I'm still figuring out how to set properties using dot notation. I have 3 files as follows... towards the end(in main), I've set the radius property and the logged it, but I'm not sure how to set the center property because it's not a float (like radius) it's an array. I originally tried something like—
ball.center = {12, 14, 16} does not work.

*My class .m file is:*

```
@implementation Sphere

-(void)setCenter:(NSArray *)center radius:(float)radius {
_center = center;
_radius = radius;
```

}
@end

*my class .h file is:*

```
@interface Sphere : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) float radius;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *center;

-(void)setCenter:(NSArray *)center radius:(float)radius;

@end
```

*and my main file is:*

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Sphere *ball = [[Sphere alloc] init];
        ball.radius = 34;
**// ball.center = an array, so how do we set that?**//

**//do I have to set the values of the array first?//** 

        NSLog(@"\nball radius %f\n", ball.radius);
**//I want to be able to log the values of the array the way I logged the radius.**

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `[]`, just like any other array.  (But, of course, you must first allocate the array.)

Comment: so—ball.center = [12, 14, 16]; ?

Comment: Well, if you want to ALLOCATE the array and assign values at the same time, use `ball.center = @[@12, @14, @16];`.  But be aware that the values will be NSNumbers -- you can't put ints in an NSArray.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on why we allocate arrays but not integers and floats.

Comment: An NSArray is an object.

Answer (score 2):

I'll reply to your question "how I can create an array with numbers", but it looks like you don't need an array at all (read all the answer :-))

The first thing that you need is to initialize your array, for example:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object1, object2, object3, nil];
```

There is also the literal that allows you to do the same thing with a friendly synthax

```
NSArray *array = @[object1, object2, object3];
```

Note that you can only insert **objects** in an NSArray and not **primitives**, so you need some NSNumber (a NSNumber is an object that represents a number).

You can use a class method to create a NSNumber

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Or the literal synthax (usually preferred for its brevity)

```
NSNumber *one = @(1);
```

So, something like this will do

```
NSArray *array = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)];
```

However, I see that you want to represent the center, usually to do it, you don't use an array of objects, you use a CGPoint, that is not an array, it is a struct that contains 1 point (i.e. X and Y), and it is perfect to represent the center!

So the code will look like:

```
@implementation Sphere

-(void)setCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(float)radius {
    _center = center;
    _radius = radius;
}
@end
```

and to use it:

```
Sphere *ball = [[Sphere alloc] init];
ball.center = CGPointMake(10, 20);
NSLog(@"my ball center x:%d y:%d", ball.center.x, ball.center.y);
```

Comment: The literal array syntax is @[@(1), @(2)]. You are missing the @ in front

Comment: Thanks, just fixed the typo.

Comment: thanks for the in-depth response, Daniele. this is exactly what I was looking for. cheers